# Why is the syntax of a Rails ` error ' with a tick, and a quote?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Take the errors below:

```
undefined method `id' for true:TrueClass
/dev/MessageBooth/db/seeds.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

the errors are surrounded by two different {quotes | ticks}.   I started searching for a very peculiar error that is not well documented, and potentially syntax related, so this is why I was paying very close attention to the syntax, and noticed this trend, but why use different encapsulating quotes?

Comment: I imagine it's supposed to look like smart quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen this syntax in various languages (mostly in C, I think). I particularly like [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17695/any-reference-on-the-usage-of-a-backtick-and-single-quotation-mark-like-this/18669#18669) explaination.